# Console error when running Rest Assured API test with testng

Tags: java, maven, testng, pom.xml, rest-assured

im trying to run an API test using rest assured with maven and tesng, during execution some error is appearing on consol, im using intellij, java 8, testng and maven 
any idea how i can fix this issue

**Error**:

```
Apr 27, 2020 1:03:58 PM org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace error
SEVERE: org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/AbstractCallSite
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad non-abstract method with no code: void org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.<init>(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray, int, java.lang.String) on public class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyMethodGen.<init>(LazyMethodGen.java:223)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.<init>(LazyClassGen.java:362)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getLazyClassGen(BcelObjectType.java:563)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1706)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1657)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1422)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1196)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:551)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:116)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:635)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.SunClassLoader.define(SunClassLoader.java:94)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader.loadAbstract(GroovySunClassLoader.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader.<init>(GroovySunClassLoader.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader.<init>(GroovySunClassLoader.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader.lambda$static$0(GroovySunClassLoader.java:40)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GroovySunClassLoader.<clinit>(GroovySunClassLoader.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.isCompilable(CallSiteGenerator.java:256)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createStaticMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.createStaticMetaMethodSite(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:112)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3496)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
    at io.restassured.internal.common.assertion.AssertParameter.notNull(AssertParameter.groovy:21)
    at io.restassured.config.SSLConfig.<init>(SSLConfig.java:192)
    at io.restassured.config.SSLConfig.<init>(SSLConfig.java:184)
    at io.restassured.config.RestAssuredConfig.<init>(RestAssuredConfig.java:41)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:421)
    at Tests.Android.API.getUserDetailsTest(API.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

**Test** : this is a sample test that im executing using testng

```
public class API {

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void getUserDetailsTest() {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "https://test.com";
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
        Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.GET,"/");
        String responseBody=response.getBody().asString();   
        int statusCode=response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Status code is: "+statusCode);
        Assert.assertEquals(statusCode, 200);    
    }
}
```

**POM** : here is sample of my POM xml file and all used dependencies

```
    <properties>
        <jre.level>1.8</jre.level>
        <jdk.level>1.8</jdk.level>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.5</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Compiler plug-in -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.level}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.level}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Added Surefire Plugin configuration to execute tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/Suites/TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- log4j2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by upgrading to JDK11

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error when I was using RestAssured 4.3.0 . I have changed it to 4.2.0 and it is no longer showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding groovy dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: have you added groovy-all and groovy both dependecies ?